# Stability of cyclohexane type species

Tags: organic-chemistry, cyclohexane

I came across a question where we have to find out the stability of species that are in chair conformations. The species are as follows:

[image]

Comparing the ['A' values](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/07/01/substituted-cyclohexanes-a-values/) tells me that compound *I, III and VI* should be most stable, but the answer given is: I,IV and V.

Can anybody tell me where did I go wrong?

Comment: You can't use A-values directly except for the first row. The others have oxygen atoms in the ring. The oxygen atoms lack flaghole hydrogens, so the steric repulsion is less. Off the top of my head, I don't remember ever seeing numbers for this, so I don't have intuition on how much it changes the A-value. However, for V/VI, I still think VI. And the repulsion between the t-Bu and the lone pairs in IV might still strongly prefer III, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Why is V according to you is correct?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write VI!

Comment: Wow, there were a lot of typos in that original comment... :(

Comment: Isn't the case same for III and IV? Because tert butyl is in equatorial position in III, so less steric repulsion will be in this case. Isn't that?

Comment: Yeah, I meant to type III... :(

Comment: @Zhe: I think H-bonding with ring O makes V more stable than VI.

Comment: But H-bonding is also possible in VI and it will even be more favourable energetically due to equatorial substituents. Isn't it @Mathew?

Comment: @Sanu_012: No, VI can't make H-bonding. I'm talking about 1,3-O atoms in the ring. It is like 1,3--axial-H interactions. Here it is lone pair of O instead. Imagine the picture. Of course, these are solvent dependent.

Comment: And what about III and IV? Which one do you think is favourable energetically? @Mathew

Comment: And sorry @Mathew, this tiny head of mine couln't visualize that picture you are talking about. It would be great if you write it as an answer with essential diagrams.

Comment: @Sanu_012: My opinion, III is more stable than IV. I'd answer the question, but you have to wait for a while because, here, now 2:00 am, so I gotto have a sleep. :-)

Comment: Okay sure. Good night :) But I also think III is more stable.

Comment: Maybe you can consider anomeric effect in V-VI.(Consider the dipole moment reason)

Comment: @B.Anshuman Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Anomeric effect Acts on such structures like VI (but anomeric effect is explained only if hydroxy group is adjacent to any of the ethers). Then the axial position of -OH group becomes more favourable. This is explained in L G Wade due to two factors: Hyperconjugation of oxygen in the ring to the ABMO of hydroxy group, and the net dipole moment of both -OH and -O- being in the same direction. As the compound looked similar, I thought to mention this effect.

Comment: @mathewmahindaratne Good call on hydrogen bonding. I missed that.

Answer (score 5):

According to the Ref.1, 5-hydroxy-1,3-dioxane (the compound of structures **V** and **VI**) both in the gaseous state and in dilute $\ce{CCl4}$ solution exists as a chair conformer, the hydroxy group in an **axial position** with an intramolecular hydrogen bond of the $\ce{O—H⋯O}$ type:

[image: 1,3-dioxanes]

Accordingly, the axial conformer (**V**) is more stable by $\Delta G^\circ = \pu{-1.2 kcal mol−1}$). Microwave spectroscopy and the $^3J_\ce{H(5eq),OH}$ coupling constant suggest that the $\ce{OH}$ group lies in the plane of symmetry $(\ce{C_{(2)}-C_{(5)}-O}\text{-plane})$ and is a part of a bifurcated hydrogen bond to the two ring oxygen atoms (Ref.2). Therefore, it is safe to say the conformer **V** is more stable than conformer **VI** between two possible conformers of 5-hydroxy-1,3-dioxane (marked with $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ oval).

It is well known that the most stable conformer of *tert*-butylcyclohexane is *tert*-butyl in equatorial position. In a 1,4-substituted version of 1-*tert*-butyl-4-methylcyclohexane, since methyl group is so small compared to *tert*-butyl group that **I** is almost exclusive in equilibrium (marked with $\color{green}{\text{green}}$ oval).

However, I wasn't so sure about stability between **III** and **IV**. There is clearly no H-bonding opportunities except theoretical chemist may argue hyper conjugation with ring oxygen by MO calculations. I leave it open for any computational chemist to prove that possibility, yet my best guess is **III** more stable between them (marked with $\color{orange}{\text{orange}}$ oval with question mark).

**References:**

1. J. C. Jochims, Y. Kobayashi, “Bifurcated hydrogen bonds in z-2-phenyl-1,3-dioxan-5-ols,” *Tetrahedron Letters* **1976**, *17(24)*, 2065-2068 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(00)93819-X).
2. Jose L. Alonso, E. Bright Wilson, “Study of an intramolecular, bifurcated hydrogen bond in 1,3-dioxan-5-ol by microwave spectroscopy,” *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1980**, *102(4)*, 1248–1251 (https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00524a005).

Comment: Okay, this is understandable. But in para 2, I think you meant to write **VI** instead of **IV**. Isn't it?

Comment: @Sanu_012: Good catch! Yes, I meant **VI**. I corrected it.:-)

Comment: That means, according to you the answer should be **I, III and V** and I can assume that the answer **I, IV and V** provided in the the answer key is wrong? Isn't it?

Comment: @Sanu_012: To my knowledge, yes. But, they might have a reason. Let's wait and see how others have responded.

Comment: Okay. Let's wait some days :)